# Mod_rewrite: rewrite only 1 URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using mod_rewrite to transform:

`www.example.com/view.php?ID=1234`

into

`www.example.com/1234`

using the following rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ view.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

which works, correctly rewriting the URL. **However**, when I go to the website itself at:

`www.example.com`

it tries to rewrite that URL as well, displaying the *view.php* page as if *ID* had been left blank, rather than displaying *index.php* like it normally would.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the questionmark from your RewriteRule. This makes the preceeding expression optional.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ view.php?ID=$1 [L]
```